# How to center the contents of 2 floating divs

Tags: html, css

I want to center the text and image of the floating divs with respect to its parent div. After trying various margin options, transform, block type, I am still stuck with no result.

```css
.main-div {
  height: 15rem;
  background: #00c6ff;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.text-div a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.text-div {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.image-div {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.cleared {
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .image-div {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="text-div">
    <h3><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">1. Trying to center the text and image</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="image-div">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzE2VnttSwJdsIARy0aq-wdVfV-ajManGwb3qwpCprqRBtd_Mv" /> </div>
  <div class="cleared"></div>
</div>
```

Any changes I make to the `.text-div,` the `.image-div` either overflows or shifts down. Few cases they overlap too.

Comment: Good job sharing the code samples, can you elaborate your question `I want to center the text and image of the floating divs with respect to its parent div.` more? A image of your expected output would help a lot :)

Comment: Desired result image link: https://imgur.com/dLasFN3

Comment: Do check the other answers, if you can't find your solution, I'll help with a snippet. All the best!

Comment: vertically centre or horizontally centre ?

Comment: Both - Horizontally and Vertically

Answer (score 1):

```
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You can use this CSS to set the div in the center as a position

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CSS flex` for that.

```css
.main-div {
  height: 15rem;
  background: #00c6ff;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /* Horizontal align when flex-direction is column */
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Align vertically as well if needed */
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Or put some space between the contents */
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  
  /* Remove the next line if you don't want main-div to be full-width */
  width: 100%;
}

.text-div a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.text-div {

  /* Div is bigger than it's content, if you want it
   * to look centered you need to center content as well
   */
  text-align: center;

  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.image-div {

  /* Div is bigger than it's content, if you want it
   * to look centered you need to center content as well
   */
  text-align: center;

  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.cleared {
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .image-div {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="text-div">
    <h3><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">1. Trying to center the text and image</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="image-div">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzE2VnttSwJdsIARy0aq-wdVfV-ajManGwb3qwpCprqRBtd_Mv" /> </div>
  <div class="cleared"></div>
</div>
```

You can find more details on the [MDN CSS Flexible Box Layout page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout), and [CSS tricks has a good tutorial in this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-div {
width: 70%;
margin-left:15%;
margin-right:15%;
}
.image-div {
width: 30%;
margin-left:35%;
margin-right:35%;
}
```

By setting these margins the left and right margin will make the div center without the need to use floats

Answer (score 0):

I've found a following work-around, but it doesn't use floating:

```css
.main-div{
  height: 15rem;
  background: #00c6ff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0072ff, #00c6ff);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-div{
  width: 70%;
}

.text-div a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.image-div{
  width: 30%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .main-div{
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="text-div">
    <h3><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">1. Trying to center the text and image</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="image-div">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzE2VnttSwJdsIARy0aq-wdVfV-ajManGwb3qwpCprqRBtd_Mv" /> </div>
</div>
```

I've also added `media query` which will center the content on small devices.

Also, You should consider using responsive images, or else image(or content) will overlap. You can make the image responsive with:

```
.image-div img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for aligning the contents to the centre. However, the image flows out of the div when resized and the media query don't seem to kick in.

Edit: solved the overlfow by ```overflow:hidden``` on the parent div. Need to figure out the media query part.

Comment: The image flows out of the `div` because the image size is bigger than the assigned `30%` to the div. With `overflow: hidden`, the image will cut off and users won't be able to see the image. So instead of `overflow: hidden`, you should consider using responsive image - as I've shown at the end of the answer.

Comment: A responsive image will change it's width and height as per it's parent element. If the screen is big, you'll be able to see big image, if screen is small, image will become small. But in either cases, image will never be cut off, as how `overflow: hidden` will cut off.

Comment: Can you eloborate on "Need to figure out the media query part"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the responsive image suggestion. I have made the changes. Coming to the media query part: The image remains alongside the text instead of moving down and behaving like its own block.

Tried the code on codepen.io and the issue still persists. Any other way to make the image slide down when the screen size decreases for mobile users?

Comment: @user11909951 when you make the image responsive, as I've shown in my answer, the image will slide down. I've just confirmed on my codepen.

Comment: If you don't want to use responsiveness and still want the image to slide down, then you'll need to change the `image-div` width in the media query.
Here's the code for this: https://jsfiddle.net/763vLapt/

Comment: If you want to use responsive, then nothing to do for the `image-div`, Here's the code for this: https://jsfiddle.net/osLgpqmn/